# How to combine drawer navigation with tabbed activity

Tags: android

I am trying to combine my drawer navigation with Tabbed activity inside it. But i have problem with the java. I already try to follow this answer [How to impliment navigation drawer and swipe tab in same activity in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917596/how-to-impliment-navigation-drawer-and-swipe-tab-in-same-activity-in-android-stu)
But i got error . it says

> com.dimas.adttest.MainHome is not an enclosing class

I already put this from my MainHome.java(Tabbed Activity)

```
mSectionsPageAdapter = new MainHome.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Into my MainActivity. Soo it be like this
MainActivity.java (Drawer Navigation)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new MainHome.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainHome.java (Tabbed Activity)

```
public class MainHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly u want to do?? the main activity and the mainhome are the same activity right?? i mean the main activity is itself the tabbed activity...?

Comment: I want to combine the drawer navigation with tabbed activity. Drawer navigation is the mainactivity.java and the mainhome.java is the tabbed activity

Comment: I want to combine it so i have a navigation in my tabbed activity

Comment: show the mainhome.java

Comment: I already update to question

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` instead of `new MainHome.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmemtManager());` .. just implement the drawer layout in the tabbed activity itself or include the tabbed viewpager in the `mainActivity` there is no need of creating MainHome.java

Comment: you mean change like this ? mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

Comment: yes just do that in the main Activity.. no need of creating MainHome.java